# JQuery issue "TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, slim-jquery

I've got this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:5000/', function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

localhost:5000 is a `flask/python` script that returns a `json` like:

```
{
  "data": [
    0, 
    0, 
    0,
```

And I'm getting:

```
$.getJSON is not a function TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function
```

Any tips where I can start untangling the whoolball?

Thanks!

Edit:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

`lib/main.js` is where the `document.ready` is located.

Thanks!

Comment: What scripts are loaded on your page? You're either not including `jQuery` or you've called `jQuery.noConflict()` at some point before this (which means that you have to use `jQuery` instead of `$` from that point on.

Comment: If he didn't load jQuery he would get an error on the $(document) already ($ not found or something)... so it might be the noConflict...

Comment: your html haven't detect your jquery library

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla Please look at my recommendation in the answer below.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You seem to be using `slim` version of `jquery` which does not have the method `getJSON` thats why you are getting this error.

Please use the full version of `jquery` instead from the below link.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js

`Slim` version of `jquery` excludes `ajax`, `animations effects` etc

Comment: I use the most current version and i still get the error.
And when i check if JQuery is even active at that point using window.jQuery, i get an true.
So JQuery is loaded but the error is still gone.
I use this snippet: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 3):

Thus happens commonly when migrating codebases from jQuery v1.x+ to v3.0+ as jQuery updated/deprecated/discontinued some of it's API.

I recommend using jQuery Migrate which will address this, along with other issues:

Get it here via CDN:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-migrate

If using Gulp/Grunt, you can import into your project using

`npm install --save jquery jquery-migrate`

Github Repository - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

Read more about jQuery v3.0+..
http://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/

Comment: True. When I went from jQuery v1.x+ to v3.0+, encountered many deprecated calls: $.getJSON( ...snip... ).success() is now .done(), .error() is now .fail(), and .complete() is now .always()

Answer (score 1):

```
function cinta(){
$.getJSON('http://localhost:5000/', function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
cinta();
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('yesss');  
});
```

This work for me in python flask

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with my piece of code,

```
$.getJson("/foo.json")
```

The issue was that my function is actually spelled

```
$.getJSON
```

NOT `$.getJson`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the full version of jquery CDN instead Slim/lite version.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

without cross-origin and integrity, I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Fetch` with `async` and `await`:

```
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch( "http://localhost:5000/"
);
  return response.json();
}


getData().then((data) => {
//... your code
})
```

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/mushigh/pen/WNGRyLb)