# Javascript bug json data in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get data from JSON file in a table format in a HTML page but I get an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function

How can I solve this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  $.getJSON("Info.json", function(data) {
    var Employee_info = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      Employee_info += '<tr>';
      Employee_info += '<td>' + value.Name + '</td>';
      Employee_info += '<td>' + value.Address + '</td>';
      Employee_info += '<td>' + value.Gender + '</td>';
      Employee_info += '<td>' + value.Designation + '</td>';
      Employee_info += '<td>' + value.Age + '</td>'
      Employee_info += '</tr>'
    });
    $('#Employee_table').append(Employee_info);
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600396/jquery-issue-typeerror-getjson-is-not-a-function)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600396/jquery-issue-typeerror-getjson-is-not-a-function

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan i also link latest jquery file in code "<link rel="Javascript" type="text/css" href="/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">"but not solve problem