# loading a json file with javascript

Tags: javascript

In a `table.js` javascript file I have the following code

```
var data = '[{"id": "234", "name":"test"}, {"id": "124", "name":"test2"}]';
```

Instead of writing the JSON directly on the table.js, I want to put it in a separate file an load it. I tried this code

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
....
});
```

I got the error

```
$.getJSON is not a function
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your code? [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) requires jQuery to be included in the page before the usage.

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600396/jquery-issue-typeerror-getjson-is-not-a-function

Comment: Add this js file: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

The [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is a jQuery method, and you aren't loading the script.

To load the script add the following tag to the `HEAD` tag of your HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In vanilla JS you can use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Fetch calls the server, and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). The first promise gets a reference to the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) stream, which we can read as [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). Returning from a Promise, returns a new Promise, and now we can access the data.

**Example:**

```js
const promise = fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/rockets/falcon1') // call the server
  .then(r => r.json()) // get the response stream and read it as json

promise.then(data => console.log(data)); // do something with the promise's result
```