# Populate HTML Select Field with JSON data queried from MySQL Database with jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to Populate Database Values to an HTML Dropdown Select Field with jQuery. I found a pretty good example I think if this is the way to go. I'm pretty new to jQuery and JavaScript.

Basically, I'm trying the same as the guy here: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/ but it is different though.

To keep it on this example, I just need the "Variety" Dropdown, no "Fruit" dropdown. I want to `SELECT savename FROM pdfform;` on page load and display the results in the "Lade Datensatz" HTML Dropdown.

[image: Picture]

But all that is Happening is that I get an empty Dropdown like the jQuery isn't executing at all. If I call the data.php directly I get JSON Data:

[image: Picture]

**index.html** including JavaScript jQuery:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="bg-light" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <form id="LoadForm" name="LoadForm">
                    <h5 class="text-center">Lade Datensatz</h5>
                    <label for="load"></label>
                    <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="load" name="load">
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        // 1st Try
        // function populatedata() {
        // console.log("populatedata Executed!");
        //     $.getJSON('/data.php',
        //         function(data) {
        //             var select = $('#load');
        //             var options = select.prop('options');
        //             $('option', select).remove();
        //             $.each(data, function(index, array) {
        //                 options[options.length] = new Option(array['savename']);
        //             });
        //         });
        // }

        // 2nd Try
        // function populatedata() {
        //     console.log("populatedata Executed!");
        //     $.getJSON('/data.php',
        //         function(data) {
        //             console.log(data);
        //         });
        // }

        // 3rd Try
        function populatedata() {
            console.log("populatedata Executed!");
            $.getJSON('/data.php');
        }

        // Good for all Trys
        $(document).ready(function() {
            populatedata();
            $('#load').change(function() {
                populatedata();
            });
            $('#load').click(function() {
                populatedata();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My **data.php**:

```html
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $dsn = "mysql:host=192.168.17.61;dbname=mvt_test";
    $username = "mvt_test";
    $password = "wqiM7n4POSW1jpJLPM3u2";

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    $rows = array();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT savename FROM pdfform");
    // $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT savename FROM pdfform WHERE name = ? ORDER BY savename");
    // $stmt->execute(array($_GET['savename']));
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Console Log:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoczo.png)

Comment: First of all, I think you misunderstood the line `$stmt->execute(array($_GET['savename']));` in your PHP file. Since you don't have parameters in your sql request (the `?` in the electrictoolbox example), your line should be `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: @abvlle: Thanks. I Edited the Main Post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not pay attention to the `jquery` you called until you edited your post and add the console log, you're calling the `Slim` version of `jquery` which excludes `ajax`. Check this :
[JQuery issue "TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600396/jquery-issue-typeerror-getjson-is-not-a-function)

You should take a closer look to your console, the error is very clear : `$.getJSON is not a function`, you have to call the full version of jquery!

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually was the biggest Problem. It is Working now with a little further tweaking. Next stop: Loading all the HTML Fields with the Selected Dataset from Database.